First hitting time of simple random walk on bounded integer interval
I'm interested in simple random walk model. For bounded integer interval $[0,1,....,n]$, the initial point is $x=0$. At each step, the random walk is made to change $x=m$ to $x=m+1$ $(p=0.5)$ or $x=m$ to $x=m-1$ ($p=0.5$) otherwise. It is important to note that for $x=0$, the only option is to move $x=1$ (boundary). I'd like to calculate the average first hitting time (the number of steps!) in which the point first hits the $x=n$, starts from $x=0$. Thanks in advance!
